# ¿Como tomar solo la primera palabra de un texto introducido por teclado?

Tags: java, eclipse

Estoy realizando un programa que me ayude a calcular los puntos de funcion de proyectos. En una parte, se deben introducir los puntos de funcion sin ajustar y debo tomar la primera palabra para que cuando entre en un if y se parezca al texto que estoy buscando, me lo sume en un acumulador. Esto me servira para saber cuantos puntos de insercion, busqueda, actualizacion o de base de datos hay y pueda efectuar unas operaciones.
Estuve buscando y lo intente con un split y subString pero no logro lo que necesito.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculo_funcion {

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner stg = new Scanner(System.in);

    int cant, n1, n2, n3, n4,n5, n6,n7, n8, n9, n10,n11, n12,n13,n14, tFA, Desarrolladores, Sueldo, Costo, OCosto, ei=0, eo=0, eq=0, ilf=0, eif;
    double PFSA = 0, HH;
    System.out.println("Introduce la cantidad de requerimientos de su sistema: ");
    cant = stg.nextInt();


    System.out.println("Tipo de complejidad que tiene su proyecto: \n 1- Bajo\n 2- Medio \n 3- Alto");
    String comp = sc.nextLine();


    switch(comp) {
    case "Bajo":
        System.out.println("Inserta los requerimientos: ");
        for(int i=0; i< cant; i++) {
            System.out.println(i+1+": ");
            String n = sc.nextLine();
            String[] text = n.split("\\ s", 1);
            if(text[0]=="Insertar"|text[0]=="Registrar") {
                ei+=1;
            }else {
                if(n=="Buscar"|n=="Consultar") {
                    eq+=1;
                }else {
                    if(n=="Tablas de Base de Datos"|n=="Tablas de BD"|n=="Tabla de base de datos") {
                        ilf+=1;
                    }else {
                        if(n=="Reportes"|n=="Reportes"|n=="Listar") {
                            eo+=1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        PFSA=(ei*3)+(eo*4)+(eq*3)+(ilf*7);
        System.out.print(PFSA);
        break;
    case "Medio":
        System.out.println("Inserta los requerimientos: ");
        for(int i=0; i< cant; i++) {
            System.out.println(i+1+": ");
            String n = sc.nextLine();
            String[] text = n.split("\\ s", 1);
            if(text[0]=="Insertar"|text[0]=="Registrar") {
                ei+=1;
            }else {
                if(n=="Buscar"|n=="Consultar") {
                    eq+=1;
                }else {
                    if(n=="Tablas de Base de Datos"|n=="Tablas de BD"|n=="Tabla de base de datos") {
                        ilf+=1;
                    }else {
                        if(n=="Reportes"|n=="Reportes"|n=="Listar") {
                            eo+=1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        PFSA=(ei*4)+(eo*5)+(eq*4)+(ilf*10);
        System.out.print(PFSA);
        break;
    case "Alto":
        System.out.println("Inserta los requerimientos: ");
        for(int i=0; i< cant; i++) {
            System.out.println(i+1+": ");
            String n = sc.nextLine();
            String[] text = n.split("\\ s", 1);
            if(text[0]=="Insertar"|text[0]=="Registrar") {
                ei+=1;
            }else {
                if(n=="Buscar"|n=="Consultar") {
                    eq+=1;
                }else {
                    if(n=="Tablas de Base de Datos"|n=="Tablas de BD"|n=="Tabla de base de datos") {
                        ilf+=1;
                    }else {
                        if(n=="Reportes"|n=="Reportes"|n=="Listar") {
                            eo+=1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        PFSA=(ei*6)+(eo*7)+(eq*6)+(ilf*15);
        System.out.print(PFSA);
        break;
    default:
        System.out.print("Error\n Por favor elija una de las tres opciones mostradas.");
    }

    System.out.println("Escribe el valor para cada Factor de Ajuste del 0 al 5 \n tomando el 5 como de mayor importancia: ");
    System.out.println("Comunicacion de datos");
    n1 = sc.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println("Precesamiento distribuido");
    n2 = sc.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println("Objetivo de rendimiento");
    n3 = sc.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println("Configuracion del equipamiento");
    n4 = sc.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println("Tasa de transacciones");
    n5 = sc.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println("Entrada de datos en linea");
    n6 = sc.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println("Interfase con el usuario");
    n7 = sc.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println("Actualizacion en lines");
    n8 = sc.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println("Procesamiento complejo");
    n9 = sc.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println("Reusabilidad del codigo");
    n10 = sc.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println("Facilidad de implementacion");
    n11 = sc.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println("Facilidad de operacion");
    n12 = sc.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println("Instalaciones multiples");
    n13 = sc.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println("Facilidad de cambios");
    n14 = sc.nextInt(); 

    tFA = n1+n2+n3+n4+n5+n6+n7+n8+n9+n10+n11+n12+n13+n14;
    double mfa = (double) (0.01*tFA);
    double PFA = PFSA*(0.65+mfa);

    HH = (double) (PFA*8);
    System.out.print("El total de Horas hombre necesarias son: "+HH);
    System.out.println("Introduce las horas diarias de trabajo: ");
    int h = sc.nextInt();
    double dt = HH/h;
    double mm = dt/28;
    System.out.println("Se trabajaran: "+dt+" dias o "+mm+" meses con un solo trabajador.");

    System.out.println("Cuantos desarrolladores se desea tener: ");
    Desarrolladores = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("De cuanto sera el sueldo mensual: $");
    Sueldo = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Ingresa otros costos del proyecto: $");
    OCosto = sc.nextInt();
    double th = HH/Desarrolladores;
    double Dt = th*h;
    double Mm = Dt/28;
    Costo = (int) ((Desarrolladores*Mm*Sueldo)+OCosto);
    System.out.println("Se trabajaran: "+Dt+" dias o "+Mm+" meses con los "+Desarrolladores+" desarrolladores.");
    System.out.print("El costo total del proyecto sera de $"+Costo);
}}
```

Entiendo que es un desastre de codigo pero hasta el momento tengo bien la idea de lo que hace pero de lo que mas depende esto son de los acumuladores, sino lo demas no sirve de mucho. Espero me haya podido explicar bien y puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 2):

Hola si lo que quieres es obtener la primer palabra de una frase puedes usar la clase  `StringTokenizer` que te ayudara a dividir un `string` en `substrings` o tokens, en base a otro `string` por ejemplo:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("introduce una frase"); 
String frase = sc.nextLine();
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(frase);
String primeraPalabra = tokens.nextToken();
System.out.println("la primer palabra es :" +primeraPalabra);
```

por lo que si pones una frase que diga "Aprendo a usar Tokens" tu salida sera:

```
introduce una frase
Aprendo a usar Tokens
la primer palabra es :Aprendo
```

Answer (score 0):

Si al guardar la frase con el .nextLine() lo sustituimos por .next() se guardara en la variable lo introducido hasta el primer espacio

```
 System.out.println("Tipo de complejidad que tiene su proyecto: \n 1- Bajo\n 2- Medio \n 3- Alto");
    String comp = sc.next();

``
```